# Solve for $z$ in $3z + \dfrac{z}{1 + i} = 10 - 4i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$3z + \dfrac{z}{1 + i} = 10 - 4i$

Can someone please tell me how to solve this problem? I've tried multiplying both sides by $1+i$ but I just get a really complex equation. Please help!

Comment: It is complex indeed.

Comment: Note:  $\dfrac 1{1+i}=\dfrac {1-i}2$

Comment: You're off to a good start by multiplying both sides by $i$. You say you get a "really complex equation"—what exactly do you get? If you show your steps we can help you figure out what to do next. It might be helpful to try to group together terms with $z$ on one side and "constant terms" on the other side of the equation.

Comment: 12-th grade math.

Comment: @aras well i subtracted 3z from both sides to get $\frac{z}{1+i}=10-4i-3z$ and then i multiplied by $1+i$ on both sides to get $z=-3zi+5+10i$ and I'm not sure what to do from there...

Comment: Your multiplication is missing a few terms if you multiplied by $1+i$.  You should have $z=(10-4i)(1+i)-(1+i)3z=-3z-3iz+\dots$

Comment: When doing complex arithmetic, it becomes even more important to fully expand the operations that are occurring, at the very least when the results don't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $(1+i)$ then you have
$$3z(1+i)+z=(10-4i)(1+i)=10+10i-4i+4=14+6i$$ so $$z(3+3i+1)=z(4+3i)=14+6i$$ and thus $$z=\frac{14+6i}{4+3i}=\frac{14+6i}{4+3i}\times\frac{4-3i}{4-3i}=\frac{74-18i}{25}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$3z + \frac {z}{1+i} = 10 - 4i$

Multiplying through by $(1+i)$ seems like a good start.

$3z(1+i) + z = (10-4i)(1+i)\\
3z + iz + z = 10 + 10i - 4i + 4\\
4z + 3iz = 14 + 6i\\
(4+3i)z = 14 +6i$

That isn't so bad.  What next?

Rather than trying to divide through as you would be inclined to do with real numbers.  I suggest multiplying by the complex conjugate.

$(4-3i)(4+3i)z = (4-3i)(14+6i)\\
(16 + 12i - 12i + 9)z = 56 + 24i - 42i + 18\\
25z = 74 - 18i$

And now that you have a real coefficient, go ahead and divide.

$z = \frac {74}{25} - \frac {18}{25} i$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{1+i}$ is just a constant, so you have: $$z(3+\frac{1}{1+i})=10-4i\implies z=\frac{10-4i}{3+\frac{1}{1+i}}$$

Use that $$\frac{a+bi}{c+di}=\frac{(a+bi)(c-di)}{(c+di)(c-di)}=\frac{(a+bi)(c-di)}{c^2+d^2}$$ to rationalise the complex fractions

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$3z + \dfrac{z}{1 + i} = 10 - 4i \iff 3\bar z + \dfrac{\bar z}{1 - i} = 10 + 4i$$

and summing/subtracting up

$$
\begin{cases}
6\Re(z)+\Re(z)-\Im(z)=20\\\\
6i\Im(z)+i\Im(z)-i\Re(z)=-8i
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases}
7x-y=20\\\\
7y-x=-8
\end{cases}
\implies x=\frac{74}{25},\, y=-\frac{18}{25}$$